# The Save Replay button is gone in Warcraft III: TFT

Tags: warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

After each game, the "victory" screen is displayed, which contains statistics about how many units you have killed etc. At the bottom of this screen, there is supposed to be a "Save Replay" button. Since I have downloaded the latest patch, however, I am unable to save replays. The "Automatically save replays" options also does not save replays (i.e. after a game, there is no replay with the name LastReplay).

I have just reinstalled the game. I noticed that before I downloaded the update, the "Save Replay" button was available, but after downloading the update it no longer shows up.

Does anybody else have this issue? Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is the official response by Blizzard

> Howdy mess and LasT,
>
> We've got a fix implemented for 1.27c. Should be out in mid January.
>   Apologies that you won't be able to save replays over the holidays.
>
> Cheers, Classic

Source: https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20752586651#post-4